# Синтаксическая ошибка в "Данные о личных предпочтениях"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено

На странице [Данные о личных предпочтениях](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data) расположилась синтаксическая ошибка:

[image: Скриншот с ошибкой]

Вместо:

> **соглашению** о конфиденциальности

правильно было бы написать:

> **соглашением** о конфиденциальности

Ведь "история действий и предпочтения охраняются" - *кем? чем?* - **соглашением**. А сейчас у вас получается так: "история действий и предпочтения охраняются" - *кому? чему?* - **соглашению**.

Comment: [Английский оригинал страницы](http://stackoverflow.com/users/prediction-data).

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю переписать страницу целиком. Например:

> ### Данные о личных предпочтениях
>
> Наш сайт запоминает, какие вопросы и метки вы просматриваете. С
>   помощью специальных алгоритмов он анализирует ваши предпочтения и
>   старается показывать только то, что вас действительно заинтересует.
>   Например, если вы живёте в Москве, то не увидите вакансий на Камчатке,
>   пока сами не начнёте их искать.
>
> История ваших действий на сайте и расчёты по поводу ваших
>   предпочтений охраняются [соглашением о
>   конфиденциальности](//stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy). Мы не
>   передаём их третьим лицам, не указанным в соглашении. Так что
>   вам не станут докучать рекламой рубашек, если вы читаете у нас про
>   моду и стиль.
>
> Мы ответственно относимся к сбору данных и используем их только для
>   того, чтобы вам было удобнее. Так мы надеемся помочь вашему
>   профессиональному росту.
>
> #### Скачать данные о себе
>
> Мы хотим, чтобы нам доверяли. Поэтому вы в любой момент можете скачать
>   информацию о ваших личных предпочтениях.
>
> `Скачать`
>
> #### Выключить личные предпочтения
>
> Личные предпочтения делают сайт удобнее для вас, но вы можете от них отказаться. В этом случае мы перестанем анализировать
>   ваши действия и в течение 24 часов удалим всё, что успели о вас
>   узнать. Это не повлияет на функционал сайта, но, возможно, вы начнёте
>   видеть менее полезное содержимое.
>
> `Выключить`